# Observer pattern updating both text fields and bar graph

Tags: java

So I'm working on an observer pattern assignment. I have 2 windows which have 4 fields each. In one window you can type in double values into 4 different text boxes and they get reflected in one of the 4 corresponding bars in the bar graph.

I am also able to change the bars in the bar graph by pressing my mouse button and it moves to where my pointer is. Now, I want to get the text field to updated as well, but I am not sure how to do this. It seems to be getting a notification that there has been a change, but I do not know how to set the appropriate text in the field. The bar frame has repaint. Do I do that for the text frame as well?

Here's my code for the 3 relevant classes so far:

BarFrame

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;
import java.awt.geom.*;

import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.event.*;

import java.util.*;

/**
  A class that implements an Observer object that displays a barchart view of
  a data model.
*/
public class BarFrame extends JFrame implements ChangeListener, MouseListener
{

       private ArrayList<Double> a;
       private DataModel dataModel;

       private static final int ICON_WIDTH = 200;
       private static final int ICON_HEIGHT = 200;
   /**
      Constructs a BarFrame object
      @param dataModel the data that is displayed in the barchart
   */
   public BarFrame(DataModel dataModel)
   {
      this.dataModel = dataModel;
      a = dataModel.getData();

      setLocation(0,200);
      setLayout(new BorderLayout());

      addMouseListener(this); // adds the mouse listener in to the bar frame

      Icon barIcon = new Icon()

      {
         public int getIconWidth() { return ICON_WIDTH; }
         public int getIconHeight() { return ICON_HEIGHT; }

         public void paintIcon(Component c, Graphics g, int x, int y)
         {
            Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;

            g2.setColor(Color.red);

            double max =  (a.get(0)).doubleValue();

            for (Double v : a)
            {
               double val = v.doubleValue();
               if (val > max)
                  max = val;
            }
            double barHeight = getIconHeight() / a.size();

            int i = 0;
            for (Double v : a)
            {
               double value = v.doubleValue();

               double barLength = getIconWidth() * value / max;
               Rectangle2D.Double rectangle = new Rectangle2D.Double
                  (0, barHeight * i, barLength, barHeight);
               i++;
               g2.fill(rectangle);
            }
         }
      };

      add(new JLabel(barIcon));

      setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      pack();
      setVisible(true);
   }

   /**
      Called when the data in the model is changed.
      @param e the event representing the change
   */
   public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e)
   {
      a = dataModel.getData();
//      for(Double d: a){
//        System.out.println(d);
//      }
      repaint();
   }


@Override
public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    double max = Collections.max(dataModel.getData());
    double value =  (double)e.getX() / (double)getWidth()* max;

    if( 30 <= e.getY() && e.getY() < 80 ){
        //first bar
        dataModel.update(0, value);
    }

    if( 80 <= e.getY() && e.getY() < 130 ){
        //second bar
        dataModel.update(1, value);
    }

    if( 130 <= e.getY() && e.getY() < 180 ){
        //third bar
        dataModel.update(2, value);
    }

    if( 180 <= e.getY() && e.getY() < 230 ){
        //fourth bar
        dataModel.update(3, value);
    }
}

@Override
public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

}
```

DataModel

```
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import javax.swing.event.*;

/**
  A Subject class for the observer pattern.
*/
public class DataModel
{
       ArrayList<Double> data;
       ArrayList<ChangeListener> listeners;

   /**
      Constructs a DataModel object
      @param d the data to model
   */
   public DataModel(ArrayList<Double> d)
   {
      data = d;
      listeners = new ArrayList<ChangeListener>();

   }

   /**
      Constructs a DataModel object
      @return the data in an ArrayList
   */
   @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public ArrayList<Double> getData()
   {
      return (ArrayList<Double>) (data.clone());
   }

   /**
      Attach a listener to the Model
      @param c the listener
   */
   public void attach(ChangeListener c)
   {
      listeners.add(c);
   }

   /**
      Change the data in the model at a particular location
      @param location the index of the field to change
      @param value the new value
   */
   public void update(int location, double value)
   {
      data.set(location, new Double(value));
    //  frame.fieldList[location].setText(Double.toString(value));
      for (ChangeListener l : listeners)
      {
//        System.out.println("l = " + l);
         l.stateChanged(new ChangeEvent(this));
      }

   }

}
```

TextFrame

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.event.ChangeEvent;
import javax.swing.event.ChangeListener;

import java.util.ArrayList;

/**
  A class for displaying the model as a column of textfields in a frame.
*/
public class TextFrame extends JFrame implements ChangeListener
{

       DataModel dataModel;
       JTextField[] fieldList;
       private ArrayList<Double> a;
   /**
      Constructs a JFrame that contains the textfields containing the data
      in the model.
      @param d the model to display
   */
   public TextFrame(DataModel d)
   {
      dataModel = d;

      final Container contentPane = this.getContentPane();
      setLayout(new BoxLayout(contentPane, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));

      ArrayList<Double> a = dataModel.getData();
      fieldList = new JTextField[a.size()];

      // A listener for action events in the text fields
      ActionListener l = new ActionListener()
      {
         public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
         {
            // Figure out which field generated the event
            JTextField c = (JTextField) e.getSource();
            int i = 0;
            int count = fieldList.length;
            while (i < count && fieldList[i] != c)
               i++;

            String text = c.getText().trim();

            try
            {
               double value = Double.parseDouble(text);
               dataModel.update(i, value);
            }
            catch (Exception exc)
            {
               c.setText("Error.  No update");
            }
         }
      };

      final int FIELD_WIDTH = 11;
      for (int i = 0; i < a.size(); i++)
      {
         JTextField textField = new JTextField(a.get(i).toString(),FIELD_WIDTH);
         textField.addActionListener(l);
         add(textField);
         fieldList[i] = textField;
      }

      setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      pack();
      setVisible(true);
   }


   /**
   Called when the data in the model is changed.
   @param e the event representing the change
*/
public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e)
{
   a = dataModel.getData();
//   for(Double d: a){
//    System.out.println(d);
//   }

}


}
```

A couple notes:
I know that it's buggy if you change the value of the bar with the maxed value (the other bars shift). That came with the code that I am supposed to extend on. I'm guessing it's that way so that it can be used as a referencing point.
I know that I can get rid of the unnecessary mouse listeners by using an adapter, but my instructions state to implement them as empty instead.

Bonus question if anyone feels like answering: is there a way to get an actual double precision on my mouse press? It always returns an integer.

Anyway, sorry for the long post. Thank you for your help in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out!
I added the following in stateChanged method in TextFrame:

```
   for(int i = 0; i < a.size(); i++){
       fieldList[i].setText(Double.toString(Math.round(a.get(i) * 10) / 10.0)); // to get 1 decimal place accuracy
   }
```